# Cannot implement custom keyboard in u-boot

Tags: keyboard, u-boot

As known, u-boot loader supports some sort of "input device system" that allows to register a set of functions (like getc, tstc, start, etc...). So I need to implement my own hardware-specific "keyboard". What should I do? Sounds simple:

1) Create at least "init", "tstc", "getc" and "start" functions in driver file.
2) In "init" call "stdio_register" to let system know about my device.
3) Call driver "init" from my custom board init code.

What the problem? Unfortunately, it doesn't work. stdio_register returns 0 (like all OK), but "start", "tstc", "getc" were never called.
I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot understand: another keyboards drivers seems to not contain any additional code for keyboard registration. Can anybody tell the truth?

Or maybe I should just hack u-boot and insert polling call somewhere in main_loop? :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have created a custom device driver.

```
struct stdio_dev kon_dev
```

Try something like this at U-Boot command line to switch console to the custom driver

```
setenv stdin kon_dev
```

Of course, your custom driver will have to be debugged before you get to the happy place. It may not work the first time.

Using netconsole is similar to what you're doing. With netconsole it's possible for example to keep stdout continuously on serial device, switch stdin to nc device (that is, "setenv stdin nc", enter commands through that netcat session a while, then switch stdin back to serial.

Comment: Joe, my custom driver cannot completely replace serial device. It was created to support only 2-3 buttons connected to GPIO pins of CPU. Maybe there even no need to attach these buttons to console...

Comment: You could look at CONFIG_CONSOLE_MUX which might allow input from both the usual input device, plus your custom driver. See doc/README.iomux.

Comment: Thank you, I've read and enabled console muxing. But it's not enough: I have added CONFIG_SYS_CONSOLE_IS_IN_ENV option and replaced custom driver init call from board_late_init() to board_init_r() right below stdio_init()